# Jquery upload files when open button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following code, the issue i have is that i am getting a error of e.originalEvent.dataTransfer is undefined.

my code is as follows
HTML

```
Select images: <input type="file" id='fileupload' name="userfile[]" multiple>
```

Javascript is as follows

```
var hot = $('#fileupload');

hot.change(function (e) 
{
     e.preventDefault();
     var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
     //send dropped files to Server
     handleFileUpload(files,hot);
});

function handleFileUpload(files,obj)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
   {
        var fd = new FormData();
        var e = document.getElementById("child_id");
        fd.append('userfile[]', files[i]);
        var filename=files[i].name;
        var status = new createStatusbar(obj,files[i]); //Using this we can set progress.
        status.setFileNameSize(files[i].name,files[i].size);
        sendFileToServer(fd,status,filename);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `files` belongs to the input field. This you'll get by the `target` attribute.

If I test the setting above, I have success with this descriptor:

`e.originalEvent.target.files`

Then, files is an array of `File` objects, containing name, lastModifiedDate, type etc.